# How to link the Tag Items to TestCaseId in Team Foundation Server 2017?

Tags: sql-server, tfs, ssrs-2014

We are trying to create a report to link the Tag Items to their TestCaseIds.
However, the tables in the TFSWarehouse are empty.  How would we link these sets of data.

Comment: What's that mean for "`Tag Items`"here? Added `Tags` in test case or files are tagged by specific Tag?

Answer (score 0):

It was very interesting - I did a search on every field on every table in the TFS database and came to know the Tags were actually embedded in XML in the rows.  This is a very unique way of placing data, as the XML rows could be readily 'read' by a browser.  However, this was very difficult to SELECT and perform JOINS on data.